# Spring 5 with hibernate 3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring5

I am little bit confused what hibernate version shall i use.

We have an application which currently using Spring 3 and Hibernate 3. We have to migrate it to Spring 5.2.6, but i am not sure if we can keep the hibernate version same or shall we upgrade. I know there are so many things changed in Spring which may not compatible with current hibernate version.

Can you please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-hibernate):

> As of Spring Framework 5.0, Spring requires Hibernate ORM 4.3 or later for JPA support and even Hibernate ORM 5.0+ for programming against the native Hibernate Session API. Note that the Hibernate team does not maintain any versions prior to 5.1 anymore and is likely to focus on 5.3+ exclusively soon.

So, I would suggest you to use the latest stable version in the 5.4 [branch](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/).